# How to boot GRUB2 into the simplest Linux shell?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub2

I've got a PC *with certainly a hardware problem*, the installed Ubuntu doesn't boot, neither does Live CDs. (Although Ubuntu is correctly installed).

(the 'normal' boot freezes after some filesystem checks / networking startup)

However, GRUB2 seems to be ok, but I can't find any way to start a simple root shell, `bash` for instance. What can I tell `GRUB 1.97-b4` to start such a shell ?

(I guess some

```
linux /boot/...
initrd /boot/...
```

)

thanks for your help and point of views

Comment: depending on your distro adding 1 or init 1 to the end of the kernel boot line should drop you to a single user mode root shell

Comment: @aking1012  `init 1` might/seems to be too much, I see some `apparmor`, `fsck`, ... that could not be loaded  (although I don't know yet for sure that the `init 1` is taken into consideration)

Comment: @aking1012 I don't know how relevant it is regarding your comment, but my ubuntu uses UpStart

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try editing your regular boot entry in grub (<kbd>e</kbd> shortcut and appending `init=/bin/sh` to end of the line beginning with `linux ...`. After you will boot it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>), you will get a root shell immediately.

Comment: @Kevin: Once you have that shell, try `/bin/bash` to have a nicer interactive shell. You may need to run `mount -t proc proc /proc` and `mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys` for various system utilities to work.

Comment: On my machine (Ubuntu 18.04 Grub 2.02-2ubuntu8.13), it did not work appending appending `init` to the recovery mode option, but it did work on the normal (non-recovery) option.

Comment: When I try this I cannot interact with the shell. It seemingly takes no input. Maybe I am missing some configuration with qemu?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand why Ubuntu does't boot.
So, if u wanna get a shell, which also means that u MUST have a kernel loaded, u need to find the kernel.

For the right installation of ubuntu, but unable to boot, use

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz... the kernel installed by Ubuntu installer.
initrd /boot/initrd.img...
```

If something wrong with the installation, u can boot from ISO file.
using:

```
loopback loop /path/to/ISOfile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper [iso-scan/filename=/path/to/ISOfile]
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
```

Thats all i know.